# put php.ini when using XAMPP

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp

I recently started playing around with building web applications. I used XAMPP to install apache distribution.

I now want to build basic file upload functionality. I have an HTML script ready (refer to A below) and a basis php script (refer to B below). I ensured that there is a directory 'upload' in the folder on my local server where both script A and script B are stored.

I read on instruction pages that I first need to put php.ini at "on". However, I can not find the "php.ini" file, and I can also not find the file_upload directive that it should be part of.

When I run the HTML script and upload a document the only thing the page shows is the php script that I wrote (so an exact copy of the text of script B below).

Can anyone tell me where I can find the file_upload directive and how I can turn on the "php.ini" file?

Furthermore, can you tell - based on the code below - if there is any other mistake that I made preventing me from uploading file?

**Script A: HTML script:**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select document to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Script B: PHP script:**

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I would expect XAMPP to have come installed with PHP activated. So you shoudl UNDO whatever you did to deactivate it

Comment: _Just checking_ Is **Script B: PHP script:** the `upload.php` script that you call in your HTML script?. If so it would be simpler to call it that in your question